# Recursive nested loop while value != null

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, linq-to-entities

I have a batch of users with that model.

```
public class AdUserModel  
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        
        public AdUserModel Manager { get; set; }

    }
```

I need to iterate inside `Manager` nesting while manager is not null and do some work. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

```
void Recurse(AdUserModel model)
{
    // Do something..

    if (model.Manager is not null) Recurse(model.Manager);
}
```

Or using an extension method:

```
static void Recurse(this AdUserModel model)
{
    // Do something..

    model.Manager?.Recurse();
}
```

---

If you have a collection of `AdUserModel`s, they can be used like this:

```
foreach (var model in userModels) Recurse(model);
// Or with the extension:
foreach (var model in userModels) model.Recurse();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! It seems that almost all I need. But in during my work I need to create Department objects with ParentDepartment set or add to ChildDepartments collection. I am researching now how it would be better to solve.

Comment: updated https://pastebin.com/drGdTVuQ

Comment: I have stackoverflow exception using this

Comment: Do you have any self-referencing objects in your collection? Or other circular relationships?

Comment: Let me check, but I don't think so. I've changed code with while(true) loop and now there is not stackoverflow, but app stucks

Comment: adUserModels.Where(x => x.Manager == x)  Empty

Comment: Try [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M7I57D) to see if you have any circular relationships.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and return

Comment: I've got an exception System.Exception: xxx has already been processed

Comment: In that case you have a circular relationship in your data, which doesn't seem right if you're modelling management hierarchies.

Comment: Nothing to do with that?

Comment: @hoozr Are you sure `model.Manager` will ever actually be `null` at the time you are calling the `Recurse( )` method from within itself? What kind of work are you doing to your model inside the method?

Comment: @AstridE. The comment above confirms that this is due to a circular relationship. For example, the following Manager references: `user1 -> user2 -> user3 -> user1`, which will recurse infinitely, or until the execution stack overflows.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay You are right; my first question was unneccessary. And I didn't see there was a fiddle of the method being used until now, but after seeing it, I realize that my second question is also unneccessary at this point.